# Spring Thymeleaf Error in finding String in Set

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I want to check if a set contains the text 'ADMIN'.

I can do below with no errors:

```
    <div th:each="r:${#authentication.principal.commRoles}">
        <div th:if="${r.code} == 'ADMIN'">
            <script>
                var isTransporterChangeable = true;
            </script>
        </div>
        <div th:unless="${r.code} == 'ADMIN'">
            <script>
                var isTransporterChangeable = false;
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
```

but when I try to use sets.contains:

```
    <div th:if="${#sets.contains(#authentication.principal.commRoles.code, &quot;ADMIN&quot;)}">
        <script>
            var isTransporterChangeable = true;
        </script>       
    </div>
    <div th:unless="${#sets.contains(#authentication.principal.commRoles.code, &quot;ADMIN&quot;)}">
        <script>
            var isTransporterChangeable = false;
        </script>       
    </div>
```

I get an error message:

> EvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'code' cannot be found on object of type 'org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet' - maybe not public or not valid?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: isn't it obvious looking at stacktrace ?  Property or field 'code' cannot be found , check that your POJO has this property

Comment: @AlmasAbdrazak Yes, it does. The first code snippet works, but not the second.

Comment: Make sure you have Getters and Setters for the field

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb Yes, there are.

Answer (score 1):

`#authentication.principal.commRoles` is a list and does not have `code`

You can get the specific Role  object and check it this way

```
th:if="${#sets.contains(#authentication.principal.commRoles, adminRole)}"
```

The correct way for Thymeleaf is

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
</div>
```

and

```
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
</div>
```